# firebase node js TypeError: Cannot read property 'toId' of undefined at exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello new to node Js

in my firebase cloud function logs

it says it cannot read property toId

I am printing out console.log(event) and the wild card toId shows the user's UID as I inspected , so what am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
  exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/user-messages-notification/{toId}/{fromId}/{message}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    console.log('This is the event:',event)

    var toId = context.params.toId
    var fromId = context.params.fromId

    console.log('User: ' + toId + ' recieved a message from  ' + fromId);

  var userRef = db.collection('Users').doc(toId);
        var getDoc = userRef.get()
            .then(doc => {
              if (!doc.exists) {
              return  console.log('No such document!');
              } else {

                  var User = doc.data();
              return  console.log('Document data:', doc.data());


              }
            })
            .catch(err => {
              //catch error does not need 'return console'
              console.log('Error getting document', err);
            });

  })
```

Comment: The string "told" doesn't appear anywhere in your code.  I don't see how the error message could be related to it.

Comment: var toId = context.params.toId         ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you typed "told" instead of "toId" (ell instead of eye).  Didn't appear in search.

Comment: What version of firebase-functions are you using?

Comment: firebase realtime database the latest version

Comment: Please be specific about the version you're using.